# SonarQube - What is "Updating Semaphore Batch?

Tags: sonarqube

I ran Maven debugger and when during "Load Module Settings" phase of Sonar analysis, Maven outputted "Updating Semaphore Batch". What does this statement mean? Does Sonar interact with either the database or the Sonar server during this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This log indicates that the batch is updating a semaphore in the DB to make sure that it is still alive. This allows tthe backend to know when a batch has been killed without letting it end properly - which could result in inconsistencies in the DB.

In upcoming versions, we're going to decouple the batch analysis from the DB to prevent any direct access to it. When this is done, this mechanism will be useless and therefore dropped.

Comment: Does Maven Sonar plugin access the database or Sonar server at this point? I am getting "Journal Flusher" and Java heap space errors and am trying to decide if it is a problem with the computer analysing the code or the computer containing Sonar server and MySQL db.

Comment: Yes, the batch analysis (may it be with Maven, Sonar Runner, Ant, Gradle, ...) still directly queries and updates the DB.